# preg_match and regex error while parsing string?

Tags: php, regex, string

I need to scrap a part of a url using preg_match but I never got what I need.
Here the example:

```
$item = "http://example.com/0229883504/?r=2-OR1&p=1";
$item = preg_match_all("/href[^\"]+/i",$item,$matches);
print_r($matches)
```

I need to return this number

> 0229883504

I tried a lot but when I `var_dump` the matches array, it gives:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => href= ) )
```

I know that the problem is within the pattern but I'm not so good in this part :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code you need:

```
$item = "http://example.com/0229883504/?r=2-OR1&p=1";
$item = preg_match_all("#http://.*?/(.*?)/.*#i",$item,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

If you need to extract the value 0229883504, you can add these lines:

```
$result = $matches[1][0];
echo $result;
```

and it will work as you can see here: http://ideone.com/H2E9I

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick for example above.

```
 preg_match_all("/http:\/\/example.com\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\//",$item,$matches)
```

or even better:

```
 preg_match_all("/http:\/\/example.com\/(.+)\//",$item,$matches)
```

However if your domains can vary use the example of the code from Aurelio :).